# Minimalistic PHP blogging engine with focus on code quality

Tags: php, blogs

I'm looking to set up a blog.

There are many "what's the best blogging engine?" questions on SO, but none totally focused on code quality.

I have done a lot of work with WordPress, and it's the #1 solution for many cases, no question. Its extendability and versatility are unmatched. But the code base is a mess, it has a huge memory footprint and extending it often isn't fun. Also, the back-end feels extremely slow on slightly older machines and becomes bearable only with Google Gears IMO. 
I'm getting less and less comfortable using it.

For that reason, I am looking for recommendations for a PHP-based blogging engine that is

- Simple, slim, and minimalistic in build
- Has good, structured, clean code, uses PHP5
- Has blogging basics: Tags, Categories, Comments
- Doesn't have to look good but needs to output good, semantic HTML / CSS so I can customize
- Supports some sort of spam control (Captcha and / or Akismet would be nice)
- I don't care whether it's database or file based

Optional:

- An API would be nice but is not mandatory
- Has a plugin system for extensions

Wet dream:

- Markdown support

Comment: How'd this turn out for you, Pekka? Did you end up with Habari? How do you like it?

Comment: @Andrew I ended up with Habari, and successfully set up a blog with it. It looks very nice and makes heavy use of PHP 5's OOP. The admin interface took some getting used to and had a few minor bugs, but all in all this was a good choice.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I see you are using WP for your website, are you still using Habari? If not, what made you stop using it?

Comment: @Lekensteyn I switched back to WP on the last re-launch because I wanted to be able to add content to the site through a mobile client for travelling. (The actual experience of using the WP iOS client didn't turn out to be great in the end, though.)

Comment: Try [Exyht](http://exyht.github.io/exyht/) built with Ember & Laravel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure exactly how many things it knocks off your list but I think [Habari](http://habariproject.org/en/) is worth a look.

They host a [demo](http://demo.habariproject.org/) you can mess with if you want to check it out quickly.

Comment: since Pekka is german, I'll throw in a few german links for Habari: http://habarimag.de, http://www.drweb.de/magazin/habari-schnelles-und-schlankes-blogsystem, http://bueltge.de/habari-einblicke/650/

Comment: @anomareh @Gordon This looks very, very good. Thanks for making me aware of it, and the links.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at [Vanilla](http://vanillaforums.org/). Mainly it's a forums script, but it also has blogging features.

I has all the things you mentioned. Except is looks good enough:

- the entire code is about 500k
- it's well structured(MVC and well done), it supports extensions
- I'm not sure about tags(for sure they are supported by extensions if not in the core)
- looks good, have template mechanism, a few nice themes are available
- there are extensions to prevent spam, I don't know if an aksimet extension is available.
- it's mysql based

Optional:
- don't know what you mean by apis
- plugins and themes supported

Wet dream should be supported, at least in theory(on my old vanilla forum it worked in a manner I didn't want to, the code was html encoded, so html tags were not supported, including links, however i've seen them working on other forums), if not extensions could solve the problem.

Regarding the spam control and user comments posting you should use 2-3 plugins(Yes plugins are supported and are called Extensions).

Comment: Cheers @php html, I have come across Vanilla in the past and it looks very interesting. For my current needs, though, it is probably already too rich in function. Still, very good to know for future uses. +1

Answer (score 1):

There's a huge number of blogging engines written in PHP - all slightly different. For my purposes, I found Serendipity to be the most apposite.

C.

Comment: +1 for teaching me a new english word. I was sure it didn't exist. And cheers, I will take a look at it if Habari doesn't cut it for me (it strongly looks that way though)