# PHP/MySQL alternatives to WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, blogs

I'm having a hard time believing there isn't already a good question with solid answers/discussion about this, but I didn't have any luck searching one up. Please link+close if you know of one. Certainly no hard feelings...

that being said,

I'm looking for a PHP+MySQL blog framework that's not named WordPress, and I have the following basic requirements:

- relatively "light" aka easily edited/hacked/augmented (clean code, good structure, etc)
- solid image support (upload, resize, etc)
- solid comments system (including some sort of human verification)

Not too bad, right?

Normally I just hop over to Wikipedia for this sort of thing, but their [List of CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_content_management_systems#PHP) is uncharacteristically lacking in cross-comparison details.

Picking through that will take me awhile. Is there anyone out there who has been down the same road as I and would like to toss out some suggestions while I peruse Wikipedia's list?

Thank you!

EDIT - I finally found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370416/minimalistic-php-blogging-engine-with-focus-on-code-quality), by the masterly Pekka

Comment: Google is your friend http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/wordpress-alternatives/

Comment: PS - in case anyone really can't think of a good reason why I'm avoiding WP, I've been there, done that, and believe there's got to be a better way... especially for someone with a little PHP ability

Comment: @martswite - But how many of those have you used? Can you vouch for any of them personally? I asked on SO because I trust the quality of the audience viewing this question more than I do other resources...

Comment: I havn't personally used any of them myself but a few people I know have used Habari and found it a pleasurable experience. One of my friends currently uses Tumblr but I dont rate it in terms of aesthetics. I personally just use blogger.....

Comment: @Andrew Heath fair point ;) are you looking for just a blog or a platform to develop sites on?

Comment: Just a blog, really. But I'd like it to be clean enough that I could expand it at will with my own additions. WP is decidedly NOT clean!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of blog frameworks in that list. As i know joomla is good and also eZ Publish. But why you don't want to use Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like Worpdress, may be you can use Joomla, It's not only designed for blogging but can be used for this purpose.

Joomla passes the HTML validator.